# Is it fine to ask for coding changes to add functionality to existing code?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I have a question closed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626477/how-to-make-question-answering-with-bert-for-any-length-text?noredirect=1#comment110921933_62626477). It was closed for not being focused enough, which says,

"Needs more focus - if your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format. This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.."

While the question has many valid answers (as do many coding questions), it for sure has a way to determine if any are correct, and it only asks one question on one problem.

And under what topics can be asked about in SO,

```
"a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"
```

It falls under these guidelines. I was told in the comments by one who voted to close it that it closed for being a homework problem, and that I should show work done to solve it, and SO is only for fixing problems. But I didn't see anything specific about fixing code in the topics required, plus the question was flagged for not being focused, not for being off-topic (which seem conflicting, how can it be asked to be more focused, implying it's clearly on topic, but also be off topic?). I also pointed out that it's not a homework problem, defined in web searches as work done for school or paid piecework (which can be debatable, but it can't be argued that it without a doubt is homework). I don't see the point in adding code with a poor attempt at solving the problem, just so it can appear more fitting with a subjective critique some have of it, which would just waste time for the person trying to work the code out. If any one person doesn't want to answer it, that's fine, but leaving the possibility up in case one is up to the challenge is more useful for SO than closing it.

Comment: Are you really complaining that you shouldn't have to write code after commenting on someone's answer that they should include code in their answer?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey  no complaints, this is an inquiry on what is acceptable or not. And yeah, people who answer are ostensibly the ones who understand what code to use (which is what is asked for), not the person asking the question, hence their reason for asking the question. These downvotes just seem to be subjective. If people don't want to answer themselves, that's fine, but I don't see a reason that matches with the rules on SO that would restrict others from answering. People are trying to learn code from each other here, not subjective critiques of a preferable way to ask questions to some

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is not to learn code or to teach. It is to build a library of high quality questions and answers for everyone who visits the site, not just the questioners. The fact that people learn from these question and answer pairs is a wonderful outcome, and one of the reasons many of us try to keep the quality high, by closing low-quality questions. Leaving them up for others who want to answer them lowers the overall quality of the site and makes it harder for people searching for the high-quality answer to their question to find it.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey And like I say in this question, where is it stated that one has to add code to something when they are asking a question on how to increase functionality with additional code? Just for errors? What would be the reason for that? What rule does that follow?

Comment: I didn't say there is a rule that says you have to have code in a question. There is no such rule. There is also no rule that says that an answer has to have code either, and it seemed to me to be hypocritical to rail against being asked to add code, only to turn around and ask for code yourself when the tables are turned and it is you who want the code.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey this is not a theoretical question here, I'm looking for specific rules that clearly say this question is not acceptable. And I don't see how what you're saying applies to my question, you're saying my question is unable to have a high quality answer? You're saying people don't go to libraries to learn?

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I didn't flag the answer. People can answer without code if they want, but it probably won't get an accepted result without code if the question is clearly asking for code. And saying it's hypocritical is like saying when if someone asks what time it is, that's hypocritical, why should someone tell them the time if they won't tell others the time. But they don't know the time, that's why they asked for the time.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey And where are these statements about SO being a library and not about learning code coming from in SO? I'm looking for specific clarifications here with links.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Heretic Monkey and you're saying it would be higher quality if the code in the question had additional code that didn't work?

Comment: @pppery exactly, there is no mention that it isn't a place to learn, which would be odd. And yes, I tried to run the code with longer text, it didn't work, and I'm trying to find out if it can be altered so it can be used with longer text. Those are the details. "This site is all about getting answers."

Comment: Ask about being stuck. Don't ask others to do your research, debugging, thinking or writing for you.

Comment: @philipxy I did, I didn't know where best to go from somewhere. Again, these critiques are not saying where in the SO rules it's saying this is the only thing that's acceptable, and the question wasn't closed for being homework. No one is pointing to an exact rule it's breaking. And really, the question just directs what an answer can be, I generally just glance at the question and then look at the answers, which have the useful code. "Ask about being stuck" means one is "asking others to do your research", those are the same things. How does one get out of being stuck without research?

Comment: I'm looking for a clear reason of why it was closed for being not focused when it seems to fit the requirements for being focused. Not for a subjective critique about whether enough effort was made. It wasn't closed for that reason, and that conflicts with why it was closed, as I've said. If the rules aren't clear then maybe they need to be changed.

Comment: This question got closed for being a duplicate,  but then all these critiques are totally unrelated about whether it's too broad. It's a simple question to add some functionality. If it were a question asking how to write a whole code to answer questions, yeah that would be too broad. The duplicate link doesn't say one should be adding codes with errors or something.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you are expecting someone to provide a specific one-line rule from the help center that explains why your question was closed. However, in this case, it is not so clear cut.

The close reason the users who voted to close your question was because it lacked focus. To other users it might seem as though your question provides a list of requirements and some existing code and requests someone to implement your requested features. As noted in the [What's on Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section, a question should be *specific*
**programing** question rather than a list of features to be implemented.

As Heretic Monkey points out in the comments above, the purpose of this site is not *primarily* to create a tutorial or teach people how to code. As noted [in the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it is a repository for professionals and enthusiasts to compile useful questions and answers. In its current form, it is not clear that your question would be of much use to future readers because it might be seen as writing code for you.

Additionally, users are expected to have performed [significant research about their question before asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). From your question, it is not clear that you have done any research. Indeed, one might wonder if there is a basic understanding of the programing language. A user might similarly wonder if someone else has written the code you provided.

Taking perhaps some of these considerations into account, three users who have earned the [privilege to cast closure votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) felt that your question was not of sufficient quality to warrant consideration for an answer in its current form.

All of that said, I fully agree with the three users that voted to close the question as too broad. However, if you edit your post to address these issues, it will automatically be placed in a review queue for consideration for reopening.

Comment: 1 I'm looking for any number of lines in the rules. 2 It didn't ask for a list of features, it did ask a specific programming question. 3 It's not a tutorial question and and is useful question and answer. 4 In any case, if you are linking to a question to explain what is expected,  then it seems the rules should be updated with links to explanations,  are people supposed to search questions to understand requirements? 6 Yes I understand how people closed it. 7 None of the critiques I've heard have explained how it doesn't follow the rules by being too broad, critiques are all about effort

Comment: The only place in the rules about showing more effort is about homework questions, and with a critique of questioning of basic understanding,  I don't think it's considered a homework question. I pointed out in the comments that by definition, doing work for oneself is not homework. So yeah, should probably update the rules.

Comment: If anything, that significant effort is only mentioned with homework problems,  this clearly implies that it's not an issue for non homework problems.